# Get the distance from a root to a node with given value in a binary tree: Algorithm correctness

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, binary-tree

Here's my code

```
 public int getDist(Node root, int value)
  {
    if (root == null && value !=0)
      return -1;//
    if(root.value == value)// we have a match
      return 0;
    if(root.getLeft()!=null)
    int left =1+ getDist(root.getLeft(),value);
    int right = 1+getDist(root.getRight(),value);
    if(left ==-1 &&  right== -1)
      return -1;//not found
    return Math.max(left,right);
  }
```

I would appreciate any feedback on the correctness of the above approach or any optimizations.

Comment: This will not do what you want since you add the values up. `left` and `right` can never be `-1` when you compare them with `-1`, they are at least `0`. You may want to move adding `1` after the last if-statement.

Comment: Just doing that wouldnt update the `left` and `right` values in the expected manner.Mind adding your comment as an answer with the modified code? Maybe Im not seeing your point

Answer (score 3):

As it stands your code won't work as intended. Consider this on the other hand:

```
public int getDist(Node root, int value) {

    // value is never in an empty subtree
    if (root == null)
        return -1;

    // found value, distance from root is 0
    if(root.value == value)
        return 0;

    // find distance from root of left subtree
    int left = getDist(root.getLeft(),value); 

    // find distance from root of right subtree
    int right = getDist(root.getRight(),value);

    // value not found in either subtree
    if(left == -1 && right == -1) 
        return -1;

    // if the value was found,
    // return the distance from the root of the subtree + 1
    return 1 + Math.max(left,right); 
}
```

All I changed was remove some superfluous checks and move the `+1` after the check for "value not in either subtree". The effect this has is the following: if the recursion finds that the value is not in a subtree, then the `return` statements will ripple up the value `-1` all the way to the root of the subtree without changing it, keeping the information "value not here" intact. If the value was found in at least one subtree, then it can't be that both `left` and `right` are `-1` so that check will fail and the `return` statement at the end will give back the intended value.

Answer (score 0):

Let `int?` indicate a variant type that is either an `int` or `null`. In C# this is `Nullable<int>`, in C++11 this is `std::optional<int>`, etc.

Then the following code will work. It is only slightly modified from your code, with the key difference being the use of `min` instead of `max`.

```
int? dist(Node root, int value)
{
    if (root == null) return null;
    if (root.value == value) return 0;
    int? left = dist(root.left, value);
    int? right = dist(root.right, value);
    if (left == null && right == null) return null;
    if (left != null && right != null) return 1 + min(left, right);
    if (left != null) return 1 + left;
    return 1 + right;
}
```

If you want, you can just use `int` and replace the appropriate occurrences of `null` with some special value like `-1`. It's my personal preference to use a nullable/optional value because it seems clearer, but it's by no means required for this problem.

Comment: The `min` instead of the `max` is only relevant if the value occurs multiple times in the tree, and in that case there is no preference over either value according to the specification in the question (distance to a node, not shortest distance). I don't see how you return anything but `0` or `null` ever, though. If the value is found somewhere, we get `0`, otherwise we get `null`, no?

Comment: @G.Bach I forgot to copy over the "1+" of course. Browser code. :)

Comment: What's the result of `1 + null`?